# My wubi usb installer can"t seem to find installation files

Tags: 14.04, lts

While attempting to install ubuntu, 14.4 LTS on my windows 7 hp mini 110-3130NR netbook   for 32 bit from an usb **wubi** installer, an error message came up and stated that it **could not find installation files.**

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 13.04, Wubi was removed. If you want a Wubi install you haveto use Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 but they are out of support if I am not wrong.

I do recommend to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a hard drive partition if you want to use Ubuntu. It is not that hard to do and there are tons of tutorials on the web.